# Does not having knowledge of ghusl bath due to a discharge invalidate prayer,if so how to compensate?

Tags: ghusl, salat-qada

What if a person doesn't know that ghusl is compulsory after a vaginal discharge due to an erotic book and prays only with woudhu for the past 2 years, will her prayers be accepted?

If not how can she compensate on those unacceptable prayers?